# General formula for coplanar vectors in higher dimensions

Tags: vectors

If I have 3 vectors, a, b and c in 3D, I can check if they fulfill $c=\alpha a + \beta b$ (i.e. if they lie in a 2D plane) for some real parameter $\alpha$ and $\beta$ by checking if $(a\times b)\cdot c = 0$. If I have 3 vectors in n dimensions, is there a similar, general formula to check if $c=\alpha a + \beta b$? Thank you!

Comment: Like row reduction?

Comment: @J.W., I'd say row reduction is more of an algorithm than a formula. (But I'd agree that row reduction is the way to go.)

Comment: @GerryMyerson:  I agree

Comment: @J.W. I was more asking for an actual way to quantify it with a number. For example in the case of 3D, assuming I have an error associated with the entries of the 3 vectors, by using that formula I won't get 0 exactly, but I might bet 1 +/- 2, which is consistent with zero. I am not sure that row reduction would help me quantify, basically, how far or close the 2 vectors are from being coplanar

Comment: Are you still here, Bill?

Comment: See also the answers to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/598934/projection-into-a-subspace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found something but I am not sure if it works. If we build the matrix $D=(a,b)$, which has dimensions $n\times 2$, then we can calculate $[D\cdot (D^TD)^{-1}D^T]c$. If this is equal to $c$, it means that the 3 vectors are coplanar. Does this hold in general?

Comment: Have you checked out my answer? Does it give the same result as yours?

Answer (score 0):

$c=\alpha a+\beta b$ if and only if $$c-{(a\cdot c)(b\cdot b)-(a\cdot b)(b\cdot c)\over(a\cdot a)(b\cdot b)-(a\cdot b)(a\cdot b)}a-{(a\cdot a)(b\cdot c)-(a\cdot b)(a\cdot c)\over(a\cdot a)(b\cdot b)-(a\cdot b)(a\cdot b)}b=0$$

Note that if the displayed equation holds, then $c=\alpha a+\beta b$ with $$\alpha={(a\cdot c)(b\cdot b)-(a\cdot b)(b\cdot c)\over(a\cdot a)(b\cdot b)-(a\cdot b)(a\cdot b)},\qquad\beta={(a\cdot a)(b\cdot c)-(a\cdot b)(a\cdot c)\over(a\cdot a)(b\cdot b)-(a\cdot b)(a\cdot b)}$$

Going in the other direction, if $c=\alpha a+\beta b$, then $$a\cdot c=(a\cdot a)\alpha+(a\cdot b)\beta,\qquad b\cdot c=(a\cdot b)\alpha+(b\cdot b)\beta$$ is a system of two linear equations in the two unknowns $\alpha,\beta$ and, if I haven't made any typos or silly errors in algebra, the solution to that system is given by the second display.